# npm error cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Tags: node.js, npm

[image: npm command with verbose log]

[image: npm shows error]

Hi, i am facing error in using the above npm command. I have Node v11.11.0 and npm v6.9.0. However, i have not been facing issues in npm v6.8.0. It looks like maybe it's an npm error itself. Please look at the logs here :

https://textuploader.com/15o67

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: The error points to this line: https://github.com/npm/cli/blob/latest/bin/npm-cli.js#L39 - suggesting its something wrong with the arguments.

Comment: yeah, how can i solve it ? cause i'm unable to use v6.9.0.